# How to get CheckBox control in GridView with SPAN using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gridview

I am trying to calculate qty total from the gridview for checked row checkbox but not able to get the checkbox control in my javascript. How can I get the Checkbox control from below generated Gridview table row in Javascript? I had attached my script below which get nothing on the script.

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" rules="all" border="1" id="grdView" style="background-color:#F2F4FF;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
         <tr>
            <td align="center">
                            <span class="chkSelected" style="display:inline-block;border-style:None;"><input id="grdView_ctl02_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="grdView$ctl02$chkSelect" /></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="grdView$ctl02$hdDocId" id="grdView_ctl02_hdDocId" value="DO0002" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="grdView$ctl02$hdScope" id="grdView_ctl02_hdScope" value="Dlv" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="grdView$ctl02$hdDocType" id="grdView_ctl02_hdDocType" value="DO" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="grdView$ctl02$hdRefNo" id="grdView_ctl02_hdRefNo" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="grdView$ctl02$hdServiceType" id="grdView_ctl02_hdServiceType" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="grdView$ctl02$hdQty" id="grdView_ctl02_hdQty" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="grdView$ctl02$hdWeight" id="grdView_ctl02_hdWeight" />
                        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

```js
function calculateTotal()
    {        
        var sum = 0.00; 
        var itemsum = 0.00;        
        var gv = document.getElementById('grdView'); 

        for (var row = 1; row < gv.rows.length; row++) {          
            var cb = gv.rows[row].cell[0].childNodes[0].find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            if (cb.checked) {
                var quantity = gv.rows[row].cells[8].innerText;
                try {
                    sum += new Number(quantity);
                } catch (err) {
                    alert(quantity);
                }
            }
        } 
        alert(sum.toString()); 
        return false;
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasted couple of days to get my correct output as below code. Hope this will help and time saving to those javascript beginner developer (like me :)). Happy coding.

```
function calculateTotal()
{
    var sum = 0.00;     
    var gv = document.getElementById('grdView'); 
    for (var row = 1; row < gv.rows.length; row++) {
        const collection = gv.rows[row].cells[0].children;
        var cb = collection[0].firstChild;           
        if (cb.checked) {
            var quantity = gv.rows[row].cells[8].innerText;
            try {
                sum += new Number(quantity);
            } catch (err) {
                //how to alert(quantity);
            }
        }
    } 
    var lbltotal= document.getElementById('lblTotalQty');
    lbltotal.innerHTML = sum.toString(); 
    return false;       
}
```